# systemctl set-environment in ExecStartPre not working

Tags: systemd

this construct within a Systemd service unit isn't working:

```
ExecStartPre = /usr/bin/bash -c "systemctl set-environment BOSH_EXPORTER_BOSH_PASSWORD=$$(echo $$BOSH_CLIENT_SECRET)"
```

After the service unit is launched, no variable BOSH_EXPORTER_BOSH_PASSWORD variable could be found in the environment like expected:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start bosh-exporter
$ sudo systemctl show-environment
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
$
```

The env variable BOSH_CLIENT_SECRET *is* set.

Thanks for pointers.